# Change component data by its method

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm working on front-end for my pet project using Angular, but I don't know much about it. I receive several jsons and put them in the fields of the app.component class. These fields are arrays of domain objects. This process goes well and jsons are successfully put into fields. This happens in the constructor. Then I want to parse the jsons by values of the keys into a new array of "ProductCard-interface type" which is described right there in the "app.component" for further use in the "product-card.component". I already did something like that with the "Icon interface" and the "icon.component". However I did not parse the values ​​from json there but entered them manually because the number of elements was fixed (only 3). I want to fill the "productCards" array according to the prescribed condition in the "fillProductCards" method, but I don't know where can I call this method. I need this array to be filled before html invoke. If I add a button with (click) action bound to this method it works fine but I need the array to be filled without any user action. When called in a div, the method is called a million times. Where can I call this method for data preprocessing? Here is the code.

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from "./domain/category";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Product} from "./domain/product";
import {Offer} from "./domain/offer";

export interface Icon {
  width: number
  height: number
  src: string
  alt: string
}

export interface ProductCard {
  productId: bigint
  offerId: bigint
  price: number
  priceOverride: number
  article: string
  productName: string
  imageUrl: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  maleCategory!: Category[];
  femaleCategory!: Category[];
  products: Product[] = [];
  offers: Offer[] = [];


  maleMenuShow: boolean = false;
  femaleMenuShow: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/categories/MALE').subscribe(result => {
      this.maleCategory = result;
    });

    this.http.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/categories/FEMALE').subscribe(result => {
      this.femaleCategory = result;
    });

    this.http.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/products').subscribe(result => {
      this.products = result;
      console.log(this.products)
    });

    this.http.get<Offer[]>('http://localhost:8080/rest/offers').subscribe(result => {
      this.offers = result;
    });


  }


  showFemaleMenu() {
    this.femaleMenuShow = true;
    console.log('success')
  }

  hideFemaleMenu(): void {
    this.femaleMenuShow = false;
  }

  showMaleMenu() {
    this.maleMenuShow = true;
  }

  hideMaleMenu(): void {
    this.maleMenuShow = false;
  }

  getProductById(productId: bigint): Product {
    let currentProduct = new Product();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      if (this.products[i].id == productId) {
        currentProduct = this.products[i]
      }
    }
    return currentProduct;
  }

  makeBig(number: number) {
    return BigInt(number)
  }

  icons: Icon[] = [
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/search.png', alt: 'Поиск'},
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/user.png', alt: 'Личный кабинет'},
    {width: 30, height: 30, src: 'assets/img/icons/cart.png', alt: 'Корзина'}
  ]

  productCards: ProductCard[] = [];
  currentProductCard!: ProductCard;
  currentProduct: Product = new Product();



  fillProductCards() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++) {
      this.currentProduct = this.getProductById(this.offers[i].productId);

      this.currentProductCard = {
        productId: this.currentProduct.id,
        offerId: this.offers[i].id,
        price: this.offers[i].price,
        priceOverride: this.offers[i].priceOverride,
        article: this.currentProduct.article,
        productName: this.currentProduct.productName,
        imageUrl: this.currentProduct.imageUrl
      }
      this.productCards.push(this.currentProductCard)
    }
  }
}
```

icon.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Icon} from "../../app.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon',
  templateUrl: './icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./icon.component.scss']
})
export class IconComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() icon!: Icon
  @Input() index!: number

  width!: number
  height!: number
  src!: string
  alt!: string
  opacity: number = 0.5

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

product-card.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ProductCard} from "../../app.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.scss']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() productCard!: ProductCard
  @Input() index!: number

  productId!: bigint
  offerId!: bigint
  price!: number
  priceOverride!: number
  article!: string
  productName!: string
  imageUrl!: string

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling fillProductCards() inside ngOnInit()?

Comment: Yes, I tried, unfortunately that did not work. For some reason arrays "offers" and "products" are still not initialised during ngOnInit() call. If I try to console.log() them inside ngOnInit() I receive [].

Answer (score 0):

A strange decision I have found though. That is a temporary crutch, so I still  wait for suggestions of proper way to do it. However I did the following:

```
  ngDoCheck() {
    let x = 0;
    if ((this.offers.length != 0 && this.products.length != 0)) {
      x++;
    }
    if (x === 1) {
      this.fillProductCards()
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, it still worked wrong because fillProductCards() was completed every time NgDoCheck() is called. So i have to add condition to the method itself and it starts working properly:

```
  productCardsFilled = false;
  
  fillProductCards() {
    if (!this.productCardsFilled) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++) {
        this.currentProduct = this.getProductById(this.offers[i].productId);

        this.currentProductCard = {
          productId: this.currentProduct.id,
          offerId: this.offers[i].id,
          price: this.offers[i].price,
          priceOverride: this.offers[i].priceOverride,
          article: this.currentProduct.article,
          productName: this.currentProduct.productName,
          imageUrl: this.currentProduct.imageUrl
        }
        this.productCards.push(this.currentProductCard)
      }
      this.productCardsFilled = true
    }
  }
```